# Printing a character array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a function print_string which takes in a character array as its argument.

For some reason I can't get it to print out if I use a while loop like

```
int i = 0;
while(str[i]!= '\0'){
    cout << str[i];
    i++;
}
```

but if I use a for loop and specify the length of the array it can.

Thanks

Comment: Is the input array zero-terminated? This is why you should provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: Could you please show us what your for loop looks like so we can compare the 2?

Comment: does the debugger show you entering the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me. My guess: you're probably experience the problem with buffering. `std::cout` is buffered, so characters first go into buffer, and then, at certain points, the contents of the buffer are put on screen.

The most typical way to force this is: `std::cout << std::endl;`

Also, tip: `std::cerr` is unbuffered, so you could use it for debugging this issue.

Comment: I have "using namespace std"  if that makes a difference

Comment: it is the same thing, I'm just a bit used to fully specifying std:: prefix